# Re-size panel component to fit screen size

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have added a `Panel` (i call it `My Panel 1`), and another `panel` within this `panel` (I call it `My Panel 2`), and then added a grid into the 2nd panel (to `My Panel 2`). When i click on the `Restore Down` or the `re-sizing` button of the browser, it doesn't shrink the components to fit the screen size. How can i solve this ?

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    height: 469,
    width: 729,
    title: 'My Panel 1',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 238,
                title: 'My Panel 2',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    height: 179,
                    title: 'My Grid Panel 1',
                    columns: [{
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'string',
                        text: 'String'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'number',
                        text: 'Number'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'datecolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'date',
                        text: 'Date'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'bool',
                        text: 'Boolean'
                    }],
                    viewConfig: {

                    }
                }]
            }]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a viewport - it automatically adjusts to the "view port" of your browser :) 
Also do not set fixed width and height if you want them to be managed automatically. 
Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/gWaCv/embedded/result/

Comment: Do  you mean to remove `autoCreateViewport: true,` ?

Comment: no, i don't mean that. you have options on how to create a viewport - autocreate is fine too. but your code does not make use of a viewport.

Comment: Can you tell me how i could make use of `viewport` from my code ?

Comment: viewport is something you typically create in your app.js Are you using MVC pattern? This guide walks you step by step and uses viewport http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-mvc-application-architecture/

Comment: yeah, good. just follow example in the jsfiddle i provided or the one in the sencha docs.